# Is it possible to find the value of $n$ in the inequality $An^{-a}+Bn^{-b}+Cn^{-c}\leq1$ with $n, a, b, c\in \mathbb N$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I want to know, there is any way to find the value of $n$ in the inequality :

> $$An^{-a}+Bn^{-b}+Cn^{-c}\leq1$$

with $n, a, b, c\in \mathbb N$ and also $A, B, C \in \mathbb N$

> *For exemple ( You can take any values you want) :* $$5n^{-3}+3n^{-4}+2n^{-5}\leq1$$ *How we can find the value of $n$ in the previous exemple, if possible ?*

Comment: "The" value of $n$? The inequality will hold for all large enough $n$. Also the left-hand side is monotonically decreasing, so you can easily find bounds for the minimum value of $n$ for which the inequality holds, and use your favourite search method to locate the actual value.

Comment: Also assuming $a<b<c$ unless $C$ is very large the term in $n^{-c}$ will be negligible compared to the other two, this could probably be solved for two terms then try $n\pm 1$ and quite similarly if $b\ge a+2$. So I would solve incrementally using this form $An^{-a}(1+\frac BAn^{a-b}(1+\frac C{AB}n^{b-c}))$.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find a value of $n$ that works, assuming $a\leq b \leq c$, you can just note that
$$
An^{-a} + B n^{-b} + C n^{-c}\leq (A+B+C)n^{-a}
$$

So, solving
$$
(A+B+C)n^{-a}_0\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow n_0 \ge (A+B+C)^{1/a},
$$

you know that the inequality surely holds for any $n \ge n_0$ (but it may also work for smaller values of $n$).

In your example this would give $n \ge 3$, which is a bit conservative, since $n=2$ also works.